# Dark mode checkbox stuck when checking for local storage

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a dark mode layout and I have everything working except for one small bug, that I can't seem to find. My dark mode is checking for a few things:

1. Checking to see system setting (OS)
2. Checking to see if there is local storage
3. Listening for a click event - on click, reverse the layout, and save to local storage.

### Problem:

When dark mode is applied, and a user refreshes the page, dark mode persists, which is working. However, the checkbox doesn't uncheck. The localstorage key-value pair changes to "light", so that's working. Something is breaking my checkbox, or keeping it on `checkbox.checked = true`.

### JavaScript:

```
const darkMode = () => {
  const page = document.querySelector("#page");
  const systemDarkMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
  const checkbox = document.querySelector("#dark-mode-select");
  const label = document.querySelector("#dark-mode-label");
  let theme = window.localStorage.getItem("theme");
  let preference; //initialize variable

//Find the system preference of the OS:
  const findSystemPreference = () => {
    if (systemDarkMode.matches) {
      preference = "dark";
    } else {
      preference = "light";
    }
    setTheme(preference);
  };


//Listen for click event, and if checkbox is true, set dark appearance & local storage:
  const setUserPreference = (e) => {

    if (e.target.checked == true) {
      preference = "dark";
      window.localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
    } else if (e.target.checked == false) {
      preference = "light";
      window.localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
    }
    setTheme(preference);
  };

//Set theme: I believe my bug lies somewhere in here. Goal is to check if the preference variable is dark or light, OR is there's a localStorage theme
  const setTheme = (pref) => {
    if (pref === "dark" || theme === "dark") {
      checkbox.checked = true;
      page.classList.add("dark-mode");
      label.textContent = "Dark Mode Is On";
    } else {
      page.classList.remove("dark-mode");
      label.textContent = "Dark Mode Is Off";
      checkbox.checked = false;
    }
  };

  checkbox.addEventListener("click", setUserPreference);
  window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", findSystemPreference);
};
```

I've tried adding more specific logic, like adding `else if (pref === "light" || theme === "dark"), but that still doesn't work.

### CodePen:

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Sackadelic/pen/jOrbGga)

### Edit:

I can break up the checking statements into separate functions like so:

```
const check = () => {
    checkbox.checked = true;
    page.classList.add("dark-mode");
    label.textContent = "Dark Mode Is On";
  };
  const uncheck = () => {
    page.classList.remove("dark-mode");
    label.textContent = "Dark Mode Is Off";
    checkbox.checked = false;
  };
```

combined with:

```
  const findSystemPreference = () => {
    if (systemDarkMode.matches) {
      preference = "dark";
      check();
    } else {
      preference = "light";
      uncheck();
    }
  };
```

But I don't know where to place the `if(theme === "dark")` statement where it won't break my checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is here

```
if (pref === "dark" || theme === "dark") {
```

Your `theme` variable is always set to `dark` since it retrieved that value from the `localStorage`, I think it should all work deleting `theme === "dark"`

EDIT: You should remove that condition from the if statement and outside everything, create a function that contains that if condition functionality

```
const setCheckboxChecked = () => { // change name and you can even abstract this function to use to set the checkbox to true/false, update text, etc.
    checkbox.checked = true;
    page.classList.add("dark-mode");
    label.textContent = "Dark Mode Is On";
}
```

And this function should be replaced to:

```
const findSystemPreference = () => {
    if (systemDarkMode.matches) {
      preference = "dark";
    } else {
      preference = "light";
    }
    setCheckboxChecked()
  };
```

What I am trying to do is to only set the checkbox to true only one time and remove that condition from the if since `theme` is always the same value hence always resolving to `true` or `false`

EDIT: [Codepen modified](https://codepen.io/agusmoles/pen/wvWKjXZ)

Comment: I use that to check if there is a `theme = dark` preference in local storage, that's why that's there. If I remove that and refresh the page, the user setting doesn't persist.

Comment: I mean what you should do is that whatever localStorage value is, you should set that initial state to the checkbox only once. And that's it with localStorage, besides that you can do whatever, switching the checkbox on/off

Comment: Edit: I see what you're saying now. Maybe I should just check if there's local storage and if it's a light theme delete local storage?

Comment: Hmmm nono. I mean localStorage should just set initial state of the checkbox. Besides that it does nothing because the functionality goes through its normal flow. So in order to do that, you should check in your `DOMContentLoaded` event that localStorage value and set the checkbox to its appropriate initial state. You got me?

Comment: Thanks for your help so far, Agustin, but I'm still confused on the flow of this. I can break up the check functions into separate functions (check edits) But I don't understand the correct way of checking the conditional `setTheme` statement. It seems to me the most logical way - setting a variable of `preference`, and then set theme based on `dark` or `light` `pref`. Where I don't follow is where to break up the localStorage statement.

Comment: Added the codepen modified. Please abstract repeated code and those things in the codepen, letting you figure it out :). Also mark the answer as correct if appropriate

Comment: Ah I see - you set the local storage like I did but then load that separately. This makes a lot of sense. Thank you! I'll abstract the repeated code. Thanks again!